# message when performing Find (script step) in FileMaker

Tags: filemaker

In OS/X I have a Customer table with the fields Name, TaxCode, and Address defined with the "required" attribute (other fields not). In a layout without any of these required fields I execute a script with a Perform Find[Restore] step which looks for records containing value 1 in another field of the same table.

I have traced the script execution and when the script reaches the Perform Find step the following Dialog pops:

"Name" is defined to require a value. Allow this field to remain empty?
         Revert Record    No   Yes

If I click Yes then comes an identical message for each of the remaining "required" fields in the table. Eventually the script finishes as expected, but of course this manual intervention makes the query cumbersome and unacceptable.

What is happening? and what can I do?

Comment: I believe the problem is with what happens **before** the script reaches the `Perform Find[]` step. When you try to perform a find, an attempt is made to commit the current record - and this attempt fails because the record does not pass validation.

Answer (score 1):

In your layout, there is a record with open state that doesn't meet your requirements. When you try to enter find mode, it fails to commit.

Try to use Get ( RecordOpenState ) to see what you get in the layout before you enter find mode – 0 is committed, while 1 and 2 are records not committed.

Also, make sure you do not have a "new record/request" script step before the "enter find mode"; it could be the reason of your trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the contents of the Customer table and found a register with all the fields empty. Once this record was deleted, the problem disappeared.

Cannot remember/explain how the empty record came about, probably some trouble during the creation process. What still surprises me is the circumstances in which Filemaker verifies the correctness of fields NOT involved in the actual Find.

Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: What surprises me is the circumstances in which that specific record became open time and again. But we won't know that without seeing what your script does before the attempted find.